# ColdFusion cfswitch

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

Can ColdFusion's cfswitch - cfcase do something like this in JavaScript?

````
switch (true) {
   case (myNuber_1 < myNumber_2):
    // do something
    break;
   case (myNuber_1 === myNumber_2):
    // do something else
    break;
}```
````

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-r-s/cfswitch.html

Comment: tldr, no, but... even in JS you wouldn't typically do that. The more common solution in JS also functions in coldfusion. (if statements)

Comment: I know CF won't be able to handle the switch(true) construct anyway, but I thought I'd ask just in case. Anyway I occasionally use  switch(true) in JavaScript because it makes the code more readable especially when you have a complex expressions you want to match against.

Comment: I would advise against using case statements like this because it's unorthodox and I suspect most experienced programmers would shake their heads. Even though javascript allows expressions in your case statements doesn't mean you should do it.

Comment: Sometimes I wish the [code-smell] tag was still around. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306314/we-are-not-reeking-of-code-smell

Comment: So how do i close this ticket by selecting the Best Answer. I don't see an option for me to select the Best Answer. Please advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on documentation, the case value cannot be a complex value. "The value or values must be simple constants or constant expressions, not variables." (https://cfdocs.org/cfcase) The complex switch case statement you have proposed requires the use of complex case values, therefor cfml case statements do not support your desired methods.

In case your wondering what a "Constant Expression" looks like, I have included an example:

```
<cfscript>
fruit = true;
switch(fruit) {
    case ("e" EQ "e"):
        writeOutput("I like fruit!");
        break; 
    case ("e" EQ "f"):
        writeOutput("I don't like fruit!");
        break; 
    default: 
        writeOutput("Fruit, what fruit?"); 
        break; 
 }
</cfscript>
```

Don't get any big ideas though, because you can't have a "Constant Expression" with a variable involved in it, nor can you have two expressions that evaluate to the same result (true and true and so on). In this example the first case evaluates to "true" and the second to "false" with the default picking up everything else. It would fail if they both evalueated to true. It would throw an error if any part of the expression contained a variable in it.

*Edited to add example.*

Answer (score 0):

You could use a closure in CF11+.

```
    <cfscript>
        function doSomething(required numeric myNum) {
            function thisAction(required numeric myNum) { 
                    if( myNum <= 10 ){
                        //do whatever
                        return "Less or equal to 10";
                    }
                    else if( myNum > 10 ){
                        //do whatever else
                        return "More than 10";
                    }
                };
                return thisAction(myNum);
            }
                writeOutput(doSomething(11));
    </cfscript>
```

Comment: In that case I don't even need the closure, the following suffices:`<cfscript>
        function doSomething(required numeric myNum) {
                    if( myNum <= 10 ){
                        //do whatever
                        return "Less or equal to 10";
                    }
                    else if( myNum > 10 ){
                        //do whatever else
                        return "More than 10";
                    }
            }
                writeOutput(doSomething(11));
    </cfscript>`